# Passing a Name to customize html field on ExactTarget triggered email from Salesforce

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, email, json

I am sending an exact target triggered email using the salesforce Apex developer. However when a member's name does not already exist on the ET side I do not know how to pass that information to ET. Right now I am passing the "Sent To" email via a JSON generator pulled from a campaign member email, and all that works out fine, it creates a new subscriber on the ET side and sends them an email, but it does not fill out the information for the name. I need this to be filled out so that the email can be customized. My current code looks like

```
 Http http2 = new Http();  
     HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
     req2.setMethod('POST');
     req2.setEndpoint('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:Braz    ilAppRecieved/send?access_token='+accessToken);
      req2.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeFieldName('From');

gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('Address', MyEmail);
gen.writeStringField('Name', MyName);
gen.writeEndObject();

gen.writeFieldName('To');
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('Address',SendId);
gen.writeStringField('SubscriberKey',SendId);
gen.writeEndObject();

gen.writeEndObject();       
String pretty = gen.getAsString();
System.debug(pretty);

req2.setBody(pretty);



 HttpResponse res2 = http.send(req2);
System.debug('Fulfillment service on Triggered Send '+ res2.getBody());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. You can pass subscriber attributes like so

```
gen.writeFieldName('To');
gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('Address',SendId);
    gen.writeStringField('SubscriberKey',SendId);
        gen.writeFieldName('ContactAttributes'); 
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName('SubscriberAttributes');
          gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField('FirstName',FirstName);
            gen.writeStringField('LastName',LastName);
         gen.writeEndObject();  
gen.writeEndObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

correction:

```
gen.writeStringField('Address',SendId); should be
gen.writeStringField('Address','someemail@domain.com');

----
gen.writeFieldName('To');
gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('Address','someemail@domain.com');
    gen.writeStringField('SubscriberKey',SendId);
        gen.writeFieldName('ContactAttributes'); 
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName('SubscriberAttributes');
          gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField('FirstName',FirstName);
            gen.writeStringField('LastName',LastName);
         gen.writeEndObject();  
gen.writeEndObject();
```

Comment: Would you like to explain in few line what you have done?